# Unhandled Promise Rejection : Existing value for key "Favorites" must be of type null or array, revived string

Tags: react-native

my problem is quite simple but I'm new to react native dev. I'd like to save multiple elements with AsyncStorage (I'm using react-native-simple-store
 a library that works like a wrapper but it's same logic) I want display all items for a key in a list , my code look like this:

```
    constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      UserInput: "",
    }
    }

SaveValue = () => {
  store.push('Favorites', this.state.UserInput)
  Keyboard.dismiss()
};

FetchValue = () => {
  store.get('Favorites').then((value) => {
    this.setState({
      favs: value
    });
  }).done();
};
```

Same thing with AsynStorage, it just update the item which is not my goal, I'd like to add a new one

```
SaveValue = () => {
  AsyncStorage.setItem("Favorites", this.state.UserInput);
  Keyboard.dismiss()
};

FetchValue = () => {
  AsyncStorage.getItem("Favorites").then((value) => {
    this.setState({
      favs: value
    });
  }).done();
};
```

This part is my view where I try to display data, you can also see that I use a text input and two buttons one to save and the other to display an array of items stored

```
  render() {
    return (

<View>

<TextInput
onChangeText={(UserInput) => this.setState({UserInput})}
placeholder= "Type something"
value={this.state.UserInput} />

<TouchableOpacity
onPress={this.SaveValue}>
<Text>Save</Text>
</TouchableOpacity>

<TouchableOpacity
onPress={this.FetchValue}>
<Text>Fetch</Text>
</TouchableOpacity>

<Text>{this.state.favs}</Text>

</View>

   );
 }
```

At this point I can see only one item, I tried to figure it out and saw that I have to use another method called push but when I changed save by push it throw me an error

> Unhandled Promise Rejection : Existing value for key "Favorites" must be of type null or array, revived string.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

it will work :)

```
 renderFavorites = () => {
        AsyncStorage.getItem("Favorites").then((favs) => {
            favs.map((fav) => {
                return (<Text> {fav} </Text>);
            });
        });
    }

render() {
    return (
        <View>
            <TextInput
                onChangeText={(UserInput) => this.setState({UserInput})}
                placeholder= "Type something"
                value={this.state.UserInput} />
            <TouchableOpacity
                onPress={this.SaveValue}>
                <Text>Save</Text>
            </TouchableOpacity>

            <TouchableOpacity
                onPress={this.FetchValue}>
                <Text>Fetch</Text>
            </TouchableOpacity>
            {this.renderFavorites()}
        </View>
    );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Solution using JSON:

```
SaveValue = () => {
  const newFavs = [...this.state.favs, this.state.UserInput];
  this.setState({ favs: newFavs, UserInput: '' }, () => {
      AsyncStorage.setItem("Favorites", JSON.stringify(this.state.favs));
      Keyboard.dismiss()
  });
};

FetchValue = () => {
  AsyncStorage.getItem("Favorites").then((value) => {
    this.setState({
      favs: JSON.parse(value)
    });
  }).done();
};
```